# How do I scrape multiple pages when the url doesn't define the page number?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to get the html from the second page of a website. I am used to the url showing the page number and letting me scrape multiple pages by manipulating that.

```
my_url = 'https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/muscle/id/1/muscle/chest'

headers = {'referer':my_url,
           'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
           'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'}
payload = {'orderByField':'exerciseName',
           'orderByDirection':'ASC',
           'page':30}
params = {'muscleID':1,
          'exerciseTypeID':[2,6,4,7,1,3,5],
          'equipmentID':[9,14,2,10,5,6,4,15,1,8,11,3,7],
          'mechanicTypeID':[1,2,11]}

r = requests.post(my_url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=params, verify=True)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. If you inspect the page, you'll see that the pagination is driven by javascript, and doesn't come directly from any server-provided API. However, if you dive down the call stack, their internal API is revealed. This means (fortunately for you), that the answer is a whole lot simpler than trying to somehow render the page/ run the javascript w/in your python script.

Check out [exercisesUtil.js](https://assets.bodybuilding.com/clientscript/trackers/exercisesUtil.js?ver=102), line 1329. That should get you started with their JSON-based API (which, you'll notice when you start to use it, is still delivering HTML strings within the JSON, so it should fit right in to you beautiful soup setup). There's a function called `refreshFinderResultSet`, the ajax call inside of which should get you started.

Comment: Woah thank you. I was only using the base url, but the link you sent me to showed me everything I need to do.